# ngIf and [hidden] not showing in IE11

Tags: angular

I have a page that uses *ngIf to show and hide validation errors.

Everything is working fine, except in IE11.

- Every polyfill is used
- [hidden] also does not work
- used angular version is 7

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Check what the compatibility mode is set to in IE, it might be running as IE7. `F12` → `Emulation` tab → `Document mode`

Comment: IE11 is support *ngIf. i used it in my application. try to check the version of IE as @Igor mentioned

Comment: It's on browserstack so thats not the case